# Creating a time series with results in a specific format - postgres (edited)

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create a series of 1 hour intervals which follows the format:
yyyymmddhh
for example: 2019-09-01 14:29 should be 2019090114
so:

```
2019-09-01 14:29 
2019-09-01 15:29 
2019-09-01 16:29 
2019-09-01 17:29 
2019-09-01 18:29 
2019-09-01 19:29
2019-09-01 20:29

2019090114
2019090115
2019090116
2019090117
2019090118
2019090119
2019090120
```

The series should preferably (not necessarily) start now() and end at a specific time in the past.
Thanks for your help

Comment: If you have two separate questions, please split them into two Stack Overflow questions. Please always add some sample data, expected output and what have you tried so far

Comment: you're right but the second part of creating a series should result in the same format, therefore I'm not sure whether I should create a new question or a 2 part question, or just a more complex quesiton: series that is formatted in the way I described

Comment: formatting should always be the very last step because it is just for formatting the output in a certain text format. the calculation steps always need the original data. so: your first step would be the interval generation. Afterwards you could format the results

Comment: In that case: Please explain what you want to do, it is not clear to me

Comment: Edited the entire question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0a0bc28c4a9b16fae1daa11169aaf155)

```
SELECT 
    to_char(gs, 'YYYYMMDDHH24')
FROM
    generate_series(now(), '2019-09-24 08:23', interval '-1 hour') gs
```

1. use `generate_series()` to generate any time or date interval series.
2. format the results with [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: Edited the entire answer ;)

Comment: do you know why wouldn't it work in a where subquery clause? 
where value in (your subquery) returns:
mismatched input '('. Expecting: ',', '.', 'AS', 'CROSS', 'EXCEPT', 'FULL', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INNER', 'INTERSECT', 'JOIN', 'LEFT', 'LIMIT', 'NATURAL', 'ORDER', 'RIGHT', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'UNION', 'WHERE', <EOF>, <identifier>

Comment: Can you please try to reproduce in a fiddle?

Comment: seems like it work in the fiddle.
In my environment however, when I manually write in the values, it works, but when I use that subquery it doesn't.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6db8f/1